# Looking for a DataGridView that allows grouping

Tags: c#, vb.net, controls

Basically I'm looking for a control that allows for grouping in a DataGridView control that can also be edited (I.E. something like DataGridView and TreeView into a single control).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage.aspx#Overview) UltraWebGrid (ASP.NET) and UltraWinGrid (Windows Forms) support grouping and can be setup as edittable grids.  These controls are part of their NetAdvantage Suite.

Answer (score 3):

Herre Kuijpers made a [OutlookGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/OutlookGrid.aspx) in CodeProject, which derives from DataGridView, and allows grouping of rows.

Answer (score 2):

DevExpress has a great [control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Tree_List/) that is a tree/gridview with grouping.

Demo [here](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxTreeListDemos/).

Index of some ASP.Net controls can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/Community/Control-gallery/).

Comment: No good ones that I know of.  You can do a combination of Trees and Gridviews but its ugly and complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Our lightweight and cheap [iGrid.NET](http://10tec.com/winforms-grid/row-grouping.aspx) supports built-in grouping with advanced features like interval grouping, and can be also used as a tree-grid.