# Showing hierarchical data in winforms datagrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have winform in which i need to show Master child information.

See the attached image to see the issue i am getting.

We want to remove this table name in between and would like once the user will click on expand button, its child records would come up in the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544162/looking-for-a-datagridview-that-allows-grouping).

The DataGrid/DataGridView doesn't implement grouping.